# Pass thread before making DB queries in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to run Rails code in concurrent threads to save some time. Specifically, since DB queries take a long time, other threads can run while a thread is blocked by a DB query. How can I get Rails to start a DB query and then pass/yield the thread while it's waiting for a response?

Comment: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/threading_and_code_execution.html

Comment: `Thread.new { <query> }`

Comment: @maxpleaner as far as I can tell, that thread still attempts to control the cpu even though it's just waiting